# How to launch route activity on google maps without destination

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, routes

How can I launch route activity on google maps from my app without specifying the destination? I am using:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=<>");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Bad behavior :

[image]

But the "to" field in google maps has "<>" string, and if I write:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=");
```

But this not working.

The idea is:
Right behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way for you to specifically go to a specific Activity in the official Maps app (empty destinations). If you look at the [Google Maps Intent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents?hl=en#overview), it exposes several intents that can launch Maps to display, search, navigate and use Street View. For searching location, you are required to have coordinates or optional queries and labels.